# SignalR HUb how use IHubContext c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I need some help knowing if they are doing something wrong with signalR. Let go:

My application is mvc. I followed the example of the tutorials and did so:

I created a RealTime class:

```
public class RealTime : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}
```

In StartUp:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    .
    .
    .
     services.AddSignalR();
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
 {
  .
  .
  .
  app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<RealTime>("/realtime");
        });
  }
```

So, I went to my controller and injected IHubContext:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<RealTime> _hub;

    public MyController
    (
        IHubContext<RealTime> hub
    )
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }
```

And at some point I use:

```
   await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "Hello Word!");
```

On my front end I did the following:

```
  var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/realtime").build();

  connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
    Swal.fire(
    'The Internet?',
    message,
    'question'
   );
  });

  connection.start().then(function () {
   //
  }).catch(function (err) {
   //
  });
```

But nothing happens. There is no error in either the back en or the front end. But nothing happens!

Can anyone tell me see I did something wrong?

Comment: Your server-side code looks right. Open your dev tools in your browser (F12) and check the JavaScript console. Any errors? Also, if you open the dev tools before `connection.start()` runs, then you can watch the traffic in the Network tab. See if the connection opens and if a message actually does come back.

Comment: My console.log is without errors. In Network tab there is a Post with the headers: Request URL:https://localhost:44375/realtime/negotiate
Request method:POST
Remote address:127.0.0.1:44375
Status code:
200
Version:HTTP/2.0
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: You should see a second request to `/realtime` with a status of `101 Switching Protocols`, which stays open. Do you see that? If it's there, you should have a "Messages" tab where you can see the messages sent back and forth.

Comment: There is not. There is only this first one. Probably a front end issue?

Comment: If I change start to this: connection.start (). Then (function () {
     //
}). catch (function (err) {
     return console.error (err.toString ());
}); In Cosole.log I see: WebSocket is not in the OPEN state

Comment: Not sure. Look at the response to the `/realtime/negotiate` request. There should be a JSON object. Look at the `availableTransports`. In my implementation, I see `WebSockets` and `LongPolling`. What do you see there?

Comment: Response payload: {"connectionId":"ORmOEixtrMb2x2gKDz9PyQ","availableTransports":[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}

Comment: So that's normal. But you don't see another request? It should be to `/realtime?id=ORmOEixtrMb2x2gKDz9PyQ` (the `id` should match the `connectionId` from the `negotiate` request).

Comment: Just a moment. I see! Not on the network, but on Console: Request URL: https: // localhost: 44375 / realtime? Id = FHizqwASgl-8zz-D3i13tw
Request method: GET
Remote address: 127.0.0.1: 44375
Status Code:
101
Version: HTTP / 1.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202351/discussion-between-rodolpho-pueyrredon-and-gabriel-luci).

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed was that you injected your hub in a Controller, try injecting it in the service/manager that gets called in that Controller.
The second thing was that you better get used with `SendCoreAsync()` instead of `SendAsync` when you aren't in the class that implements Hub.
The third thing i can suggest you to do is to put `.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information) and then .build();`
Also, put this to not get an error: `import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";`
Also start the connection and display a message to know if the connection is established

```
connection.start().then(function () {
   console.log("signalR connected")
  }).catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err)
  });
```

And I would put the connection.on only after starting the connection

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>{
        Swal.fire(
        'The Internet?',
        message,
        'question'
       );
      });
```

Hope I helped you !

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. I found the solution, although ugly it works.

I put before opening the connection the following snippet:

```
  Object.defineProperty(WebSocket, 'OPEN', { value: 1, });
```

So my js was like this:

```
 var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("/realtime")
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
  .build();

 Object.defineProperty(WebSocket, 'OPEN', { value: 1, });

  connection.start().then(function () {
     console.log("signalR connected")
  }).catch(function (err) {
     return console.error(err)
  });

  connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
     Swal.fire(
      'The Internet?',
       message,
      'question'
     );
  });
```